# When I use Task<ObservableCollection<class>> in Xamarin, it gives me error whenever I convert it using Json Deserializer

Tags: xamarin, observablecollection, xamarin.uwp

I have an API call whenever a page was navigated in Xamarin and I'm using Prism as the framework. Here is my code

```
 public override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(parameters);

        ObservableCollection<GetStudyDto> result = await GetStudyDetail(2);
        if (result != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
protected async Task<ObservableCollection<GetStudyDto>> GetStudyDetail(int studyId)
    {
            StudyDetail = await apiService.GetStudyById<ObservableCollection<GetStudyDto>>($"/Study/", studyId);
        return StudyDetail;
    }
```

Whenever I use the ObservableColletion as to bind my class, it give me error.

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[CRCRevamp.Mobile.Models.Dto.GetStudyDto]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>   To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized...

But whenever I did not bind my class to ObservableCollection, it work very fine.

Here is my example JSON response from the API:

[JSON Object from API]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the JSON didn't get posted correctly, but I suspect the problem is that the JSON is structured as an object and not an array. `ObservableCollection` only works if the JSON corresponds to an array.

To get around the (presumably) poorly structured JSON, you can use a `Dictionary<string, MyClass>` and then call `AsEnumerable` to create an `IEnumerable` and then convert it to an `ObservableCollection`.

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeSerialize<Dictionary<string, MyClass>>(jsonString);
var collection = new ObservableCollection(dict.AsEnumerable());
```